# The University of Southern California team

Tags: grammar

*The University of Southern California team looked at the behaviour of 65 students over a* *10-week term. (An excerpt from the article from BBC)*

Is this sentence OK? In the previous post India Prime Minister Vs. Indian Prime Minister Vs. India's Prime Minister the users came to conclusion that the best choice is India's Prime Minister and that India Prime Minister is a little bit ambiguous. I think that sentence from BBC should be as follows: *The University of Southern California's  team looked at the behaviour of 65 students over a 10-week term.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard way of referring to researchers affiliated with an academic institution, or to a representative of an organization. Typically no possessive is used. With *India's Prime Minister*,  "India" is a collective noun referring to the country and its people; the Prime Minister is an elected official *of* the country, and so the possessive is appropriate.  With institutions, the researchers are not *of* the university, but affiliated with it, and that affiliation is expressed adjectivally.

```
The Harvard researchers ....

University of California psychologists...

The AMA spokesman...

Cambridge archaeologists have unearthed...

A team of MIT engineers...
```

But we would say *Harvard's president*, or *MIT's Dean of Students*.

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, it is just saying the location (in this case a university) of the "team".
It is not saying that the team "belongs" to the university, which would be possessive and then written as "University of Southern California's".

Comment: In many cases, this usage has nothing to do with the physical location of the team.  For example, when the Trojans play at Stanford, "the U.S.C. football team is travelling to Northern California."  In American English, possessives are rarely used in this scenario.